# Getting current value and start observing on MutableProperty

Tags: swift, swift2, reactive-cocoa

I have MutableProperty. When I create new object I want to get current value of MutableProperty and start observing.

Such as:

```
    let mutableProperty = MutableProperty<Driver?>(Driver(id: 1, name: "John"))
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = mutableProperty.value?.name

    mutableProperty.signal.observeNext{driver in
        label.text = driver?.name
    }
```

Is it possible write it better ?

Comment: you can use implicit closure params: `{label.text = $0?.name}`

Comment: Can you write full syntax please ?

Comment: `mutableProperty.signal.observeNext{label.text = $0?.name}`

Comment: Yes but this returning new signals. Not current value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the value immediately:

```
let mutableProperty = MutableProperty<Driver?>(Driver(id: 1, name: "John"))
let label = UILabel()

mutableProperty.producer.startWithNext{ driver in
     label.text = driver?.name
}
```